# photo loads in chrome but not in firefox or IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

This photo http://www.example.com/there-used-to-be-a-photo-linked-here.jpg loads in chrome but not firefox or IE.

I am a Front End designer/dev answering a support issue for a client, we thought they were missing a style sheet in FF and IE but the image specific url doesn't even work.

Has anyone ever experienced this? What could be the problem / resolution?

Comment: Please copy your code here so we can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is somewhere on that server.  If I run this:

```
wget -O /dev/null -S 'http://www.allsaintschurch.com/uploads/all_saints_catholic_school/image/sitebg3.jpg'
```

Then about 4 times out of 5 the server responds with an error page; 1 time out of 5 it responds with an image.

If I then have wget send the same UA string as chrome, I get the image response about 90% of the time instead of 20%.  So not only is the server being flaky, it's doing that in a UA-string-specific way...

I'd probably start by looking into whatever UA sniffing logic might be in place on the server.